# H2 Database error message localization

Tags: java, database, h2

I have a problems with H2 Database exception messages. The language of the messages corresponds to the OS language(I'm using Windows). Is it possible to turn off localization feature to get messages only on English?

Comment: Currently, H2 error messages are in the current language, plus always also in English (concatenated to the translated message). Why do you want to get them *only* in English? Each message also has an error code (SQLException.getErrorCode()) by the way.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's currently not possible, but:

H2 error messages are in the current language, plus always also in English (concatenated to the translated message).

Why do you want to get them only in English? Each message also has an error code (SQLException.getErrorCode()) by the way.

(I added this as an answer because the person who asked the question doesn't seem to read the comments).

Answer (score 0):

```
...
catch (SQLException e) {
  ErrorMessage = (e.getMessage().split("\n").length > 1) ? e.getMessage().split("\n")[1] : e.getMessage().split("\n")[0];
}
```

Comment: That's only acceptable for throwaway code because it depends on details of how the message is formatted, and you have no guarantee that this format will be maintained. For anything you want to keep around, it's a terrible solution.

Comment: Agree with you ... and used it for a long time :)